# References for a notion related to radially lower semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $E$ be a real vector space, $C\subset E$ be a nonempty convex set and $z\in C$. Let $f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\textbf{(A)} \quad f(z)\leq\limsup_{t\downarrow 0}f(z+t(w-z))\quad \forall w\in C.
$$
Note that if $f$ is radially lower semicontinuous at $z\in C$, i.e.
$$
f(z)\leq\liminf_{t\downarrow 0}f(z+t(w-z))\quad \forall w\in C
$$
then $f$ satisfies property **(A)** at $z$.

**Questions:**

1) Where can we find the references for property **(A)**?

2) Can someone put a name for the property **(A)**?

Thank you for all kind help and comments.

Comment: In the second inequality, did you mean to type $\geq$ instead of $\leq$?